# process start arguments with variable not working

Tags: .net, vb.net, console-application

i do this in console application .net
import system,io,net,text,forms,threading
add reference system.windows.forms

```
Public command As String
Public core As New BackgroundWorker
Public ffReader As StreamReader
Public strFFOUT As String
Public myprocess As New Process
Public StartInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo

Public Sub Main()
    AddHandler core.DoWork, AddressOf core_DoWork
    AddHandler core.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf core_RunWorkerCompleted
    
    command = "-i ""path\test.mkv"" -vf ""setting"" -r 0.40 ""output"" -v quiet -stats"
        
    If (core.IsBusy) Then
        core.CancelAsync()
    Else            
        core.RunWorkerAsync()
        Console.ReadLine()
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub core_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs)      
    StartInfo.FileName = "CLI/ffmpeg_4_2_2"
    StartInfo.Arguments = command
    StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    myprocess.StartInfo = StartInfo
    myprocess.Start()
    
    ffReader = myprocess.StandardError
    
    Do
        strFFOUT = ffReader.ReadLine()
    Loop Until strFFOUT = Nothing Or strFFOUT = ""  
End Sub

Public Sub core_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    MsgBox("ok")
End Sub
```

i have problem with >>> StartInfo.Arguments = command

when i use like this it works

```
StartInfo.Arguments = "-i ""path\test.mkv"" -vf ""setting"" -r 0.40 ""output"" -v quiet -stats"
```

but this not work.. why?

```
StartInfo.Arguments = command
```

Comment: Maybe `core_DoWork` is called before `command` is initialized? Set a breakpoint to see what is the value of `command` at the time you use it.

Comment: command variable is correct sir but still not working, i try this same code in winform it works but i want to use this in console app

Comment: now i know, code above will work if test.mkv and exe is in the same dir

Comment: Then the issue is the working directory, not the command line.